# How to modify a string date to the correct format in Adobe Flex?

Tags: string, apache-flex, date, format

My Adobe Flex app relies on taking a user's details from Facebook, which will later be stored into my database. My remote server has a default date setting of yyyy-mm-dd, yet the birthday field retrieved from Facebook is the American mm-dd-yyyy as a string. I have decided that it makes sense to use my server's setting, especially as I can use the CURDATE() function. This leaves me in a tricky situation; so how would I go about modifying the string?

I imagined I would have to split the returned value into 3 sub values of day, month and year, then paste them back together in a different order. I have no idea how this would be done in Flex though. Can anybody help?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dateStr:String = "04-29-2012";
var parts:Array = dateStr.split("-");


if(parts == null || parts.length != 3)
{
  // Input error
}

dateStr = parts[2] + "-" + parts[0] + "-" + parts[1];
// Result : 2012-04-29
```

Comment: Thankyou for this, but before I test it I must ask if the dateStr.split("-"); means that the string is broken up into parts that are divided by -?
If so then I mist amend it to dateStr.split("/"); because Facebook returns it in a mm/dd/yyyy manner.

Comment: Yes, the argument is the split character. Replace it with `dateStr.split("/")` if that's what you want. Please accept the most helpful/correct answer to your question by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use inbuild DateFiled Class for Dates manipulations. Following method can be used to parses a String object that contains a date and returns a Date object corresponding to the String.

```
stringToDate(valueString:String, inputFormat:String):Date

eg.
 var dob:Date = DateField.stringToDate("06/30/2005", "MM/DD/YYYY");
```

For more Details refer Adobe Helps on DateField.